# Why is there no sound while playing audio from a SSH session?

Tags: audio

I've been banging my head for several dozens of minutes against the wall until I realized my Pi (B+) did play audio indeed. The only thing is it seems to only play from a TTY (i.e. an interactive text console), not from a virtual session, e.g. from a remote SSH connection.

If I log directly on the Pi with my USB keyboard and play an audio file, it works:

```
aplay /usr/share/pyshared/pygame/examples/data/house_lo.wav
omxplayer -o local /usr/share/pyshared/pygame/examples/data/house_lo.wav
```

If I run the same commands from a remote SSH session, no sound. Same happens regardless of HDMI or audio jack.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Mmmh. That's really strange. I cant think of a good reason either. My Pi sounds well on ssh. What's your distribution (not that it should matter)?

Comment: Raspbian/Wheezy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my... t'is really st00pid indeed!

The reason is my TV, which I'm using as a monitor with multiple video/audio inputs, only plays sound along with the *selected* video source! When I'm typing commands from my SSH session, the selected video source is that of my desktop tower, which switches off the [RCA or HDMI] sound input from my Raspberry Pi. Of course, when I'm using the USB keyboard that is connected to the Pi, the proper video source is selected (so I can see what I'm typing) hence I can hear sound coming from it.

Damn'it. Shame on me for being so immensely dumb.

Laughs in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Don't be so hard on yourself we have all had that face to palm moment.

Comment: Well, I'm actually laughing at me in fact. I thought I had to share this episode to its conclusion as well :-D.